# Is it possible to physically stretch US paper currency?

Tags: organic-chemistry, materials

This is not a facetious question.

I am curious how one can physically stretch US paper currency, which is allegedly 75% cotton and 25% linen. Unlike cotton or linen fabric, paper currency does not appear to stretch when wet, hot, etc.

Is there a chemical process that can be applied to paper currency that will allow it to be stretched, but that may also keep the ink on it?

Edit: It should be noted that this is for personal use only -- I have no intent to distribute or circulate modified currency.

Comment: Tampering with currency may not be a good idea.  Find out if linen stretches.  Cotton does.

Comment: I would be doing this for personal use only. It does appear that linen does not stretch -- however I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the chemisty or material properties of the bills to allow them to stretch.

Comment: Anything can be stretched within limits. I think there is a law prohibiting the defacement or modification of money. Bills run thru the washer and dryer [one time] come out nice and crisp and shrunk so there is some empty space in the formula. Since paper making usually involves pressing the wet pulp into sheets and currency is rather dense I would think that there is not much leeway in further expansion. You could try an Instron or try soaking and pressing with a hot iron between cloth. The common way to enlarge things nowadays is to take a high resolution color accurate photo and enlarge.

Comment: @jimchmst - I am aware of that law, however this is for personal usage only and not for redistribution. I'm also unaware of this law (for bills) ever being enforced. Printing and rescaling is not an option here, I'd like to retain the original physical origin.

Comment: If you can't do it with a bill, try a coin in a press.

Comment: Another way to stretch currency  is to spend it judiciously. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Fibers hardly stretch, i.e. they have a very high modulus in the direction of the fiber. Woven *fabric* does stretch, and differently depending on the direction, because the fibers are oriented in a regular (rectangular) pattern. One direction has straight fibers and is very stiff, perpendicular they are woven and more elastic, and at a 45° angle, you can also distort the pattern, so the modulus is even lower.

Perhaps US dollar bills contain a [nonwoven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonwoven_fabric) of some kind. Or several layers of fabric oriented in an an angle to each other.